# Url.Content is not showing image in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have a model class Registration in which I have a photo property which is saving the URL of the photo, my photos are saved in the images folder onto the root.

Now when I am trying to show the images it is not showing the image I have cross verified that the image is present there.

I have tried   `<img src="@item.Photo" width="100" height="100" />`

```
@*<img src="@item.Photo" width="100" height="100" />*@
```

also I have tried

```
<img src="@Url.Content(@item.Photo)" height="25px" width="50px" />
```

my path becomes `/imges/previous theme.jpg` even adding `~` in start it is still not showing the result, I have images folder onto the root and inside that I have previous theme.jpg file

It should show the result as image, even after removing the `url.Content`

```
<img src="@item.Photo" />
```

is also not working.

Comment: I would suggest to check if image has set BuildAction to CopyIfNewer or CopyAlways.

Comment: what data does `item.Photo` contain?

Comment: What is the *rendered* HTML output?

Comment: item.Photo contains the URL which comes from DB and same URL is present in the project directory ~/imges/previous theme.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Content(@item.Photo)` is likely the binary representation of your image. An `img src=` tag must contain a url to the image, not the binary representation of the image itself

Comment: @item.Photo contains the URL not the binary Image ~/imges/previous theme.jpg

Answer (score 0):

i think you should press F12, in the console tab you can see your wrong path image, and you can fix the path base on it.

Answer (score 0):

Razor has been changed a little with ASP.NET MVC 4 beta.No more @Url.Content.
Now, instead of

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/path")">
```

you can use

```
<img src="~/path">
```

Kindly check what you are getting in the console. check the path is correct.